# Property regarding Lebesgue Outer Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In real variables by Michael Spigel on page 34, the author says and proves that if $E$ is any given set contained in an open set $O$, then the Lebesgue outer measure of $E$ is less than Lebesgue outer measure of $O$ plus any arbitrary positive $\varepsilon$.
However, on page 35 in proof of problem 2.4, it says that the Lebesgue outer measure of an open set $O_k$ is *less than* the Lebesgue outer measure of $E_k + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}$.

How can both be true?

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: $\varepsilon / 2^k$ is arbitrary as much as $\varepsilon$ is. Aren't you familiar with arbitrary positive real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in Problem 2.3, there is an open set $O_k$ satisfying both inequalities, that is,
$$
m(E_k)\le m(O_k)\le m(E_k)+\frac1{2^k},
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.
But not all open sets $O_k$ satisfy both inequalities!

Comment: but isn't this contradictory? . How can both inequalities be satisfied if you have strict inequality

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up some different ideas. It is true that if $E \subseteq O$, then $m^*(E) \leq O$. More carefully, $m^*(E) = \inf\{ U \mid E \subseteq U \, \textrm{for open}\, U\}$. Consequently, you can always find some open $U$ so that $m(E_k) \leq m(U) \leq m^*(E_k)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$.

It is true that if $E$ is measurable, then there exists some open $U$ so that $m^*(U-E)<\epsilon$ etc.

Comment: measure of U is length of U and which is also Lebesgue outer measure of U. if both inequalities hold then isn't this contradictory?

Comment: the measure of $U$ is the length of disjoint open intervals that make up $U$

Comment: They're both saying that the measure open covers come pretty close to the measure of $E$.